# Converting hex string representation to float in python

Tags: python, hex, ieee-754

I have data in IEEE 745 hexadecimal format: `0x1.5c28f5c28f5c3p-1`

How would I convert this to a float in python? is this a standard module?

Comment: @Kevin: The "p" is similar to "e" but using a base of 2 instead of 10.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> float.fromhex('0x1.5c28f5c28f5c3p-1')
0.68
```

It's in the standard library, [`float.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex).

Answer (score 9):

Ah ha:

It's in the standard library, "float.fromhex",

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex

Comment: IMO this should be combined with Ignacio's answer and accepted. This lacks code, his lacks a link to the docs.