# invalid literal error when converting hex to int python

Tags: python

Am trying to convert this hex value to int and I get invalid litrel error in python 3.7

```
>>> int('1.222664064E9', 16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '1.222664064E9'
```

Comment: The `E` does not mean that it's a hex value but 1.22...*10^9

Comment: I was wrong, it was a float value, Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `float.fromhex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34002545/4518341):

```
>>> float.fromhex('1.222664064E9')
1.1333982959172886
>>> int(_)
1
```

Although are you sure it's hex? It looks like a float in exponent notation, where `E9` stands for `* 10 ** 9`:

```
>>> float('1.222664064E9')
1222664064.0
>>> int(_)
1222664064
```

Comment: I am 0.99E2% sure that it's exponential notation... maybe swap the two parts of the answer?

Comment: @tobias_k I prefer it as-is. OP's saying it's hex, so I'm taking their word for it, but offering my reservation.

Comment: @tobias_k But now you're vindicated, lol :)